# Possibility of Inserting iphone contact with Deleted ABRecordID?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was wondering if it possible to add iPhone Contact with Deleted ABRecordID.

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its impossible because the ABRecordID is a unique identifier so you can replace it. 
but you can't insert a new iPhone contact [ABRecordRef] with deleted ABRecordID

Answer (score 0):

already discussed in this forum [ABRecordID for a record in addressbook(unique id for inserted record in addressbook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939756/abrecordid-for-a-record-in-addressbookunique-id-for-inserted-record-in-addressbo)

Comment: yes i see the discussion before but i want to insert contact to Deleted ABRecordID.
so i wanna edit the question.
thanks for you attention.