# Get the ABRecordID from newly added Address Book Object ios

Tags: ios, addressbook

I have an application that adds Contacts to the Address Book in iOS, and all I need is to store the ABRecordID or ABRecordref as soon as I save the contact.

```
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressbook, newPerson, &theerror);
ABAddressBookSave(addressbook, &theerror);
```

This question is extremely similar, but I don't understand the answer: [ABRecordID for a record in addressbook(unique id for inserted record in addressbook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939756/abrecordid-for-a-record-in-addressbookunique-id-for-inserted-record-in-addressb)

How do you know the

```
ABRecordID ABRecordGetRecordID (
ABRecordRef newPerson
);
```

Some help here would be fantastic - thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply call `ABRecordGetRecordID(newPerson)` after you've saved the address book (before that, there won't be a valid ID).

```
//...
ABRecordID recordID = ABRecordGetRecordID(newPerson);
```

An `ABRecordID` is the same as an `int_32` (a 32-bit integer).

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks omz you da man. Gonna accept your answer in 2 minutes when I'm allowed.

Comment: Its always giving -1 as ABRecordID with native contact picker ABRecordRef in ios 8.1

Comment: @Abhishek this is a complete guess but maybe since you don't get contact permission from the user when using the ios 8 native contact picker apple is hiding the record id by always returning it as -1?

Comment: @danny Yes you are right, iOS 8 create copy of contact picked,  so person reference is not available in db and hence ABRecordGetRecordID provide -1

Comment: @Abhishek Hi. I am stuck in getting ABRecordGetRecordID in swift. I am always getting 1. Can you please help me. I need it very badly.

Comment: @EktaPadaliya With current iOS, you can always use CNContact and it will provide you identifier as well which is unique among contacts on the device.

Comment: @Abhishek So identifier and ABRecordGetRecordID is same right?

Comment: @EktaPadaliya First- ABRecordGetRecordID is available iOS2.0- iOS9.0,  ABAddressBook (ABRecordGetRecordID) -  The unique ID of record when the record exists in the Address Book database.,  CNContact (identifier) - The identifier is unique among contacts on the device. It can be saved and used for fetching contacts next application launch. Copied from developer.apple :)

Comment: @EktaPadaliya yes this looks similar to RecordId